# Как подменить адрес в url nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

Сейчас конфиг вот такой:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name           some-site.ru www.some-site.ru;

        proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP

        client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads

        chunked_transfer_encoding on;

     location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size 10m;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://some-ip:port/admin/;
        }
}
```

При таком конфиге происходит простой редирект на адрес указанный в proxy_pass, мне же нужно чтобы при этом в адресной строке браузера отображался урл указанный в server_name.

Comment: Во-первых, первые два `proxy_set_header` в данном случае не применились, т.е. в бекенд ушёл заголовок `Host: some-ip:post`. Во-вторых, тут нет никакого редиректа, так что ищите его в бекенде.

Comment: сейчас при переходе по адресу сайта указанного в server_name происходит ошибка http://some-ip:port/admin/admin/vacancy/vacancymodel/, как мне правильно сделать прокси чтобы было вот так http://some-ip:port/admin/vacancy/vacancymodel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему, конфиг получился вот такой:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name           some-site.ru www.some-site.ru;

        proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP

        client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads

        chunked_transfer_encoding on;

     location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size 10m;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://some-ip:port/admin/;

        }
     location /admin/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size 10m;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://some-ip:port/admin/;
        proxy_redirect http://some-ip:port/admin/ /;
        }
     location /static/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size 10m;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://some-ip:port/static/;

        }


}
```